# GLEW CMake создание файла конфигурации статическая линковка

Tags: c++, opengl, cmakelists

Пытаюсь привинтить OpenGL к VS2019 (с++). Слинковать GLFW проблем не составило. все просто. а с GLEW возникли проблемы: не было файла CMakeLists.txt. В документации по GLEW я ничего не нашел. Помогите пожалуйста: где найти этот CMakeLists.txt? CMake я пользуюсь 2 раз))

Comment: Какой еще CMakeLists.txt? Вы уверены, что вам нужен cmake? Тогда при чем тут Visual Studio?

Comment: @Dmitry не понял что и где вы искали, но в `cmake` по дэфолту есть модуль `FindGLEW`, так что просто используйте `find_package(GLEW)`

Comment: CMake кидает ошибку: CMake Error: The source directory "C:/Users/dmati/Programs/VisualStudioProjects/libs/glew-2.1.0" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.

Comment: build, который есть в zip у меня не работает. мне надо пересобрать проект. CMake требует CMakeLists.txt. Но где его найти и как его написать для glew - непонятно.

Comment: без кода CMakeLists.txt и параметров сборки которые вы запускаете по этой ошибке вряд ли что можно сказать

Comment: настройки CMake (если это оно) : Visual Studio 2019, x64, default settings. source код - папка с glew(с оф. сайта .zip) build указал там же, но с \build

Comment: А CMakeLists.txt нет! в этом и ошибка! где его можно найти?

Comment: @Dmitry 1) это не параметры сборки, 2) если `CMakeLists.txt` вообще нет - то что вы тогда пытаетесь собрать `cmake`-ом? Вы понимаете, что `cmake`-у нужен `CMakeLists.txt` для сборки?

Comment: Я понимаю, что нужен CMakeLists. но я не знаю, где его найти

Comment: Попробовал добавить /build/cmake/CMakeLists.txt в главную дирректорию

Comment: вылетает ошибка на этих строках:

Comment: configure_file (${GLEW_DIR}/glew.pc.in ${GLEW_DIR}/glew.pc @ONLY)

Comment: if(NOT TARGET uninstall)
  configure_file(
      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_uninstall.cmake.in
      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/cmake_uninstall.cmake
      IMMEDIATE @ONLY)

Comment: @Dmitry слушайте, вы понимаете, что чтобы собрать что-то с помощью `cmake` вам нужен `CMakeLists.txt`? Если у вас нет вообще никакого файла с этим именем, то что вы тогда пытаетесь собрать по средствам `cmake`? И с чего вы решили, что это что-то можно собрать `cmake`-ом?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch ну сказали человеку, что CMake - крутая система сборки (соврав), вот он и пытается.

Comment: @KoVadim я извиняюсь, а не назавете ли мне "крутую систему сборки", которая соберет без файла конфигурации?

Comment: ок. тогда вопрос: как собрать glew под windows x64? (получить .dll) Т.к. иначе на меня ругается компилятор, что исходные конф. компьютеров не совпадают (всм библиотеки и моего проекта).

Comment: Итоговая задача: получить папку, в которой будут \include и \lib со всеми необходимыми файлами для glfw и glew

Comment: @Dmitry а не хотите ли сказать откуда вы исходный код взяли то?

Comment: http://glew.sourceforge.net/

Comment: отсюда zip скачал

Comment: @Dmitry предоставте прямую ссылку, чтобы не нужно было искать/гадать что конкретно вы там скачали

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/glew/files/glew/2.1.0/glew-2.1.0.zip/download

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch тут шутка была в другом. CMake генерирует файлы для сборки, но не собирает. Я знаю, это сложно:). Похоже автор вопроса хочет самостоятельно собрать библиотеку и качает общие сорцы. А ему всего то нужно подлинковать корректно. Он решает задачу с размахом

Comment: окей, ну наконец хоть что-то прояснилось. Зайдите в папку build и запустите `cmake -G "Visual Studio 2019" cmake`. Подозреваю что вы просто не оттуда пытались запустить

Comment: @KoVadim я что-то не понял, то, что ТС пытается скоиплировать glew - это понятно, но при чем сдесь: "CMake генерирует файлы для сборки, но не собирает"? Мне кажется что начало и конец комментария у вас несколько не связаны...

Comment: 1) CMake из build запустил - ошибка осталась(что не удивительно).

Comment: 2) Я хочу использовать OpenGL для обучения. В многих проектах. поэтому хочу максимально упростить подключение библиотек.

Comment: @Dmitry приведите вывод `cmake` который вы получили после запуска

Comment: CMake Error: The source directory "C:/Users/dmati/Programs/VisualStudioProjects/libs/glew-2.1.0/build" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.

Comment: @Dmitry ну я же вам показал как запустить - то что вы делаете - неверно. Запустите так, как я вам указал

Comment: кажется, у мня все получилось. запустил CMake из /build/cmake

Comment: Блин. я собрал проект и получил 3 файла: glew32d.lib, libglew32d.lib и glew32d.exp. в ввод компилятора добавил glew32d.lib. вылетела ошибка у компилятора "Ошибка LNK2001 неразрешенный внешний символ "glewExperimental". надо ли еще что-то куда-то подключать? (всм в самой студии)